# Gapps script Logger.log function, is there size limit?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an email about 27Kb size.

The function `Logger.log(message.getBody());` returns about 7.9Kb of content.

I've tried with `Logger.log(message.getRawContent());` which also returns about the same size and not the full payload.

Is this connected to Properties limit 9kb?

Comment: No, the truncated log content has nothing to do with the Properties Service value limit of 9kb.  The documentation for [Logging Custom Messages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#logging_custom_messages) states: quote: "The logs can only hold a limited amount of data, so avoid logging large amounts of text." End quote.  But it doesn't give a spec for what the limit is.  You'll need to write out the content to some external place if you want to see all of it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is connected to the Properties limit, but Logger.log definitely has a character limit as you are seeing.

You can use console.log for Strackdriver logging to log larger items, up to 100k per entry.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging

Comment: Although, now I've realised that if I Logger.log() message in a for each loop, Logger will display each getBody() up to a specific part that is in size about 7.9Kb. That now puzzles me.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your original question, the limit I was referring to applies to each Logger.log call. In addition to that limit, a limited total number of Logger.log entries will be displayed in the log viewer. If you exceed the latter limit, you'll see a 'truncated' notice at the top of the viewer. In both cases, using stackdriver logging is the best workaround.

Comment: I will ask on google groups on this one. I do not get any truncated message warning. The log just ends there.

Comment: an individual Logger.log() call will cut off after a certain amount of text, you are seeing 7.9kb, so that is probably the magic number. There is no truncated message when that happens, it just cuts off.

Comment: the same error in 2022 with you console.log ... "Logging output too large. Truncating output."